# Is there a way to put an event handler on menu element?

Tags: go, fyne

I don't think I need these menu subitems. Can I somehow handle clicking on the menu element itself?

Something like this:

```golang
menu := fyne.NewMenu("Menu Element")
menu.Action = func() {
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A menu without the popup sub-items is just a row of buttons isn’t it? It should be possible to make that with HBox and Button widgets or maybe you want a toolbar instead?

Comment: Ohhhhh, you're right, sorry, sorry. To be honest, I'm very new to fyne and I didn't really read the docs yet. I've checked things presented in fyne_demo and that's all I knew about fyne capabilities up until now.